# Why the graphs (dots) were all cleared after minimizing to toolbar and maximizing the console window, but text was still on it?

Tags: c, winapi, graph, console-application, pixel

I drew graphs (dots) by calling [`SetPixel Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here are the problems:

1. Why the graphs (dots) were all cleared after minimizing to toolbar and then maximizing the console window, but text was still on it?
2. How to prevent the graphs drawn on the console window from erasing unexpectedly?

Any suggestions/feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the Window does not know about the dots, eg. they are not redrawable by a Window that handles their repainting, they cannot be repainted.  The console window holds the text and can repaint it, it does not know about your pixels.

Don't draw graphs on a console window.  Draw them on a GUI component canvas.

Comment: Why? The console window know the dot I drew because the handle to device context was passed into SetPixel(). Doesn't it?

Comment: That allows you to draw the dots, but still does not allow the console window to repaint them:(

Comment: @Kevin The entry point does not decide between a console and a GUI application. It's the subsystem compiled for that does; it's passed to the linker using the `/SUBSYSTEM` switch. This, however, merely controls whether or not the system allocates a console for a process. Other than that there is no difference between a GUI and a console application.